# Cannot view bounty details in Android app

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, bounties, android-app

In the Stack Exchange Android app, we can view details as to why a particular post was closed by tapping an icon in the bottom segment.

However, even though the Bounty Available segment is visible, we can't see details about the bounty, such as who placed it, when it expires and why it was placed.

[image]

---

- **Stack Exchange**: 1.0.29
- **Android**: 4.4

Comment: Worth to mention that the iOS app does show this info, so it's pure design matter and not API limitation.

Comment: Ah, that's interesting. Also,  @ShadowWizard, thank you for editing the image; I seriously need to find an image resizing app just for MSO posts...

Comment: It's matter of adding "l" to the image URL, imgur already keep resized versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added in version 0.1.30, note that it won't show the reason why someone started the bounty because that information isn't available using the API yet.

Comment: Verified! However, how accurate is the time string supposed to be? I got a bounty that ends in an hour ([this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18945029/) one), but the app says that it ends in "1 days".

Comment: @Chris anything below 24 hours should say "today" in app. I'll double check the logic.