# Bounty reason gone

Tags: bug, bounties, ios-app

I think the bounty's reason and the addition information by the bounty offerer is missing in the info box.

[image: right here]

Is this a bug? Or is it intentional?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"The reason why someone started the bounty ... isn't available using the API yet", according to [Kasra Rahjerdi](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228415/259867), the SE mobile team lead. This is a limitation that both iOS and Android apps have to live with.